# Solve the differential equation $ \dfrac{ d^2x }{ dt^2 } + 6 \dfrac{ dx }{ dt } + 9x = 4t^2 + 5 $ using variation of parameters

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Would solving $ \dfrac{ d^2x }{ dt^2 } + 6 \dfrac{ dx }{ dt } + 9x = 4t^2 + 5 $ using variation of parameters require integration by parts or can I solve it without knowing integration by parts?

I'm not sure if I'm just using the method wrong or if it requires integration by parts. I'm new to variation of parameters, and I haven't encountered integration by parts. Thanks.

The non homogeneous characteristic equation is $ r^2 + 6r + 9 = 4t^2 + 5 $

The characteristic homogeneous equation is $ r^2 + 6r + 9 = 0 $

$ \Rightarrow (r + 3)(r + 3) $

$ \Rightarrow r = -3 $

$ \therefore x(t) = C_1e^{-3t} + C_2te^{-3t}$ is the general solution for the homogeneous differential equation.

I now find the particular solution.

$-e^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{te^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{W(x_1, x_2)} dt + te^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{W(x_1, x_2)} dt$

The Wronskian $W(x_1, x_2) = e^{-6t} $

$-e^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{te^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{W(x_1, x_2)} dt + te^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{W(x_1, x_2)} dt $
$= -e^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{te^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{e^{-6t}} dt +
te^{-3t} \displaystyle\int \dfrac{e^{-3t}(4t^2 + 5)}{e^{-6t}} dt$

Comment: @JackyChong Yes but I'm not sure if I'm just using the method wrong or if it requires integration by parts. I'm new to variation of parameters, and I haven't encountered integration by parts.

Comment: Could you type up some of your work?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes. I will do that now.

Comment: Yes. You do need integration by parts.

Comment: @JackyChong Are you sure I didn't just make a mistake?

Comment: I think you want "$\mathrm{e}^{-6t}$" in those last two denominators.

Comment: It should be $e^{-6t}$ on the last line. Other than that, everything seems okay.

Comment: My thanks to both of you. So everyone agrees that this requires integration by parts to solve?

Comment: Yes. Simplify your integrand then use integration by parts.

Comment: @JackyChong Ok. Thank you.

Comment: It seems weird to have an "$x$" in front of the second integral.

Comment: @EricTowers That's another mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: So you want me to evaluate your last integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the general case of $$I_k=\int t^k e^{r t}\,dt$$ Using integration by parts $$u=t^k \implies du=k t^{k-1}\,dt$$ $$dv=e^{r t}\,dt\implies v=\frac{e^{r t}}{r}$$ makes $$I_k=\frac{t^k e^{r t}}{r}-\frac k r\int  t^{k-1} e^{r t}\,dt=\frac{t^k e^{r t}}{r}-\frac k r I_{k-1}$$ with $I_0=\frac{e^{r t}}{r}$.

If you already heard about the incomplete gamma function, almost from definition, you would have $$I_k=-\frac{t^{k+1}} {(-r t)^{k+1}} \Gamma (k+1,-r t)$$ which, in the case where $r<0$ reduces to $$I_k=-\frac{\Gamma (k+1,-r t)} {(-r )^{k+1}} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int e^{r t} \sum_{i=0}^na_it^i dt  = \frac{1}{D} e^{rt} \sum_{i=0}^na_it^i = e^{rt} \frac{1}{D+r}\sum_{i=0}^na_it^i = e^{rt}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{r}  \frac{1}{1+D/r}t^i =  
$$
$$
e^{rt}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{D}{r}\right)^j t^i = e^{rt}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{i} \left(-\frac{D}{r}\right)^j t^i = e^{rt}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{i} \frac{(-1)^j}{r^j} \frac{i!}{(i-j)!} t^{i-j} 
$$